# How to toggle show/hide individual a tags

Tags: jquery, toggle

I am attempting to make it so when i click on a subheading it shows the paragraph and clicking it again hides the paragraph. I want all 3 paragraphs to do so separately and not together.

I have got it working to an extent; clicking the  tags shows/hides all content. The expectation is you click one  tag and it should show/hide just that paragraph.

```
<style>
    #details #class #wind{
        display:none;
    }   

</style>    


</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <header><img src="images/logo960wt.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt=""/></header>
  <main> <h1>Towards a Zero Electricity Bill</h1>

<h2> text Intro .</h2>




 <h3> <a href=#details>Solar PV Solutions</a></h3>
  <div id=details>   
<img src="images/pv250.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt=""/>
<p> Paragraph text </p>

<div class="divider2em"></div>
</div> 
    <h3> <a href=#details> Geothermal</a></h3>
     <div id="class">
      <img src="images/geo250.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt=""/> 
 <p> Paragraph Text </p>
        <div class="divider2em"></div> </div>

    <h3> <a href=#wind> Wind Turbines </a></h3>            
   <div id="wind">
<img src="images/turbine250.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt=""/> 
     <p> Paragraph Text  </p>
      <div class="divider2em"></div>
      </div>

</main>
  <footer>Copyright &copy; 2019</footer>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>


<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('h3').click(function(){
    $('#details').toggle();
    $('#class').toggle();
     $('#wind').toggle();   
 })


 })


</script>   






</body>
</html>
```

The expectation is you click one  tag and it should show/hide just that paragraph. But the result is clicking the  tags shows/hides all content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

     $('h3').click(function(){         
        $(this).next("div").toggle();
      });

    });
</script>
```

see demo
https://codepen.io/shihab92/pen/GVNLGZ

Comment: This absolutely works for the bottom 2 h3's  but unfortunately not the very top one, clicking on it i get "not found".

Comment: i have given a demo here . see all the h3's are working

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find()` and `.attr("href")` to get the target id and then use `.toggle()` on this id.

Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('h3').on("click", function(){
     var target = $(this).find('a').attr("href"); 
     $(target).toggle();
   })

 })
```

```css
#details #class #wind{
        display:none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <header><img src="images/logo960wt.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt=""/></header>
  <main> <h1>Towards a Zero Electricity Bill</h1>

<h2> text Intro .</h2>




 <h3> <a href=#details>Solar PV Solutions</a></h3>
  <div id=details>   
<img src="images/pv250.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt=""/>
<p> Paragraph text 1</p>

<div class="divider2em"></div>
</div> 
    <h3> <a href=#class> Geothermal</a></h3>
     <div id="class">
      <img src="images/geo250.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt=""/> 
 <p> Paragraph Text 2</p>
        <div class="divider2em"></div> </div>

    <h3> <a href=#wind> Wind Turbines </a></h3>            
   <div id="wind">
<img src="images/turbine250.jpg" width="250" height="250" alt=""/> 
     <p> Paragraph Text  3</p>
      <div class="divider2em"></div>
      </div>

</main>
  <footer>Copyright &copy; 2019</footer>
```

Or if the paragraph is always right after the `h3`, you can use `.next().toggle()` instead.

```
$('h3').on("click", function(){
  $(this).next().toggle(); 
})
```

Comment: This works on the middle and bottom tag, but unfortunately not the first, clicking on it i get, "not found"

Comment: It work fine in the snippet. Did you change anything in your code?

Comment: I saw that as well and i was confused. upon putting this code in a new HTML file it has worked perfectly, Thank you very much!